# Clickable dots on Bokeh Plots

Tags: javascript, python, plot, bokeh

I'm working on a dashboard where the user clicks on one of many dots on a regular scatter plot to get more information about that dot. Each dot represents a group of data, and when clicked on, the user should be able to see a table in which the related group of data is listed.

The table will be listed right next to the plot, and the rows will change every time a new dot (or multiple dots) is selected.

I'll then need to add filters to this table, so it needs to be interactive too. The plot does not change during filtering, only the related data in the table will.

I've seen the following example, which achieves the exact opposite that I want to achieve:

```
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn, Toggle

from random import randint
import pandas as pd

output_file("data_table_subset_example.html")

data = dict(
        x=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
        y=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
        z=['some other data'] * 10
    )
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#filtering dataframes with pandas keeps the index numbers consistent
filtered_df = df[df.x < 80]

#Creating CDSs from these dataframes gives you a column with indexes
source1 = ColumnDataSource(df) # FIGURE
source2 = ColumnDataSource(filtered_df) # TABLE - FILTERED

fig1 = Figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=200)
fig1.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source1)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="x", title="X"),
        TableColumn(field="z", title="Text"),
    ]
data_table = DataTable(source=source2, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

button = Toggle(label="Select")
button.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source1=source1, source2=source2), code="""
        var inds_in_source2 = source2.get('selected')['1d'].indices;
        var d = source2.get('data');
        var inds = []

        if (inds_in_source2.length == 0) { return; }

        for (i = 0; i < inds_in_source2.length; i++) {
            inds.push(d['index'][i])
        }

        source1.get('selected')['1d'].indices = inds
        source1.trigger('change');
    """)

show(column(fig1, data_table, button))
```

I tried replacing *source1* and *source2* inside the button callback in an attempt to reverse the filtering (i.e. choose a point on the figure and filter the data table). But the data table is not filtered at all, instead the row that corresponds to the data point is simply selected. Any idea how to filter out the rest of the rows that are **not** selected on the plot?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes, but I think the question is too broad for SO. For instance it's not clear whether you'd want a standalone (non-server)  Bokeh document, or whether you'd want a Bokeh server application (maybe you don't know yourself yet!) For more open ended questions like this that will require a back and forth conversation, the project mailing list is a better resource: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh

Comment: @bigreddot I've included an example and edited my question. Could you please check again? I'd prefer not using a Bokeh server if possible for some other reasons, but can switch to it if necessary. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in another question: [Bokeh DataTable won't update after trigger('change') without clicking on header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683840/bokeh-datatable-wont-update-after-triggerchange-without-clicking-on-header)

Apparently the data table change needs to be triggered too.

Comment: Any time you update a data source's data "inplace" (i.e. not by replacing `.data` wholesale) in BokehJS, regardless of whether the data source backs  a plot or a table or something else, it will need an explicit change trigger.

Comment: bigreddot, got it. Thanks!