# Bokeh Data Table Linked to Select Widget

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am trying to create a Bokeh datatable that is linked to a select widget using a customJS callback. The idea is that when I change the select, the data table will update to show only the relevant rows that correspond with chosen select value. My Code is as follows:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource, CDSView
from bokeh.models import CustomJS


output_file("CatDog.html")




select = Select(title="Animal", options=["Cat","Dog"])

source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(Animal=["Cat","Cat","Cat","Cat","Dog","Dog","Dog","Dog",],Breed=["Siamese","Persian","Bengal","Burmese","Lab","Golden", "Poodle","Pug"]))

filteredSource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(Animal=[],Breed=[]))

columns = [TableColumn(field="Animal",title="Animal"),TableColumn(field="Breed",title="Breed",sortable=True)]

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source,filteredSource = filteredSource), code="""
var data = source.data;
var f = cb_obj.value;
var d2 = filteredSource.data;
d2['Animal']=[]
d2['Breed']=[]


for(i = 0; i < data['Animal'].length;i++){

if(data['Animal'][i]==f){

    d2['Animal'].push(data['Animal'][i])
    d2['Breed'].push(data['Breed'][i])
}

}

alert(d2['Breed'])
filteredSource.change.emit()

""")

select.js_on_change('value',callback)

data_table=DataTable(source=filteredSource,columns=columns )
data_table_unfiltered=DataTable(source=source,columns=columns )
show(widgetbox(data_table,select,data_table_unfiltered))
```

The alert correctly displays the rows that I would expect depending on which category select is on but the "filteredSource" DataTable does not update, it stays blank. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to make this work, you need to trigger a change on the Data Table itself. This question has actually been asked before here: [Bokeh DataTable won't update after trigger('change') without clicking on header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683840/bokeh-datatable-wont-update-after-triggerchange-without-clicking-on-header)

None the less, rearranging your code slightly to the below fixes the problem (using bokeh 0.12.14)

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource, CDSView
from bokeh.models import CustomJS


output_file("CatDog.html")

select = Select(title="Animal", options=["Cat","Dog"])

source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(Animal=["Cat","Cat","Cat","Cat","Dog","Dog","Dog","Dog",],Breed=["Siamese","Persian","Bengal","Burmese","Lab","Golden", "Poodle","Pug"]))

filteredSource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(Animal=[],Breed=[]))

columns = [TableColumn(field="Animal",title="Animal"),
           TableColumn(field="Breed",title="Breed",sortable=True)]


data_table=DataTable(source=filteredSource,columns=columns, width=800 )
data_table_unfiltered=DataTable(source=source,columns=columns, width=800 )

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source,
                              filteredSource=filteredSource,
                              data_table=data_table), code="""
var data = source.data;
var f = cb_obj.value;
var d2 = filteredSource.data;
d2['Animal']=[]
d2['Breed']=[]


for(i = 0; i < data['Animal'].length;i++){

if(data['Animal'][i]==f){

    d2['Animal'].push(data['Animal'][i])
    d2['Breed'].push(data['Breed'][i])
}

}

filteredSource.change.emit()
// trigger change on datatable
data_table.change.emit()

""")
select.js_on_change('value',callback)
show(widgetbox(data_table,select,data_table_unfiltered))
```

Comment: Apologies for the redundancy! With that,thank you very very much this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer with use of CDSView, BooleanFilter.
Run with Bokeh 2.2.3

````
from bokeh.models import CDSView, BooleanFilter
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource, CDSView
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

output_notebook()

select = Select(title="Animal", options=["All","Cat","Dog"])

source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(Animal=["Cat","Cat","Cat","Cat","Dog","Dog","Dog","Dog"],
                                  Breed=["Siamese","Persian","Bengal","Burmese","Lab","Golden", "Poodle","Pug"]))

booleans = [True for i in source.data['Animal']]
view1 = CDSView(source=source, filters=[BooleanFilter(booleans)])

columns = [TableColumn(field="Animal", title="Animal"),
           TableColumn(field="Breed", title="Breed", sortable=True)]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=800, view=view1)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, view=view1), code="""
var data = source.data;
var f = cb_obj.value;
for(var i = 0; i < data['Animal'].length; i++){
    if(data['Animal'][i] == f || f == 'All'){
        view.filters[0].booleans[i] = true;
    } else {
        view.filters[0].booleans[i] = false;
    }
}
source.change.emit();
""")

select.js_on_change('value',callback)
show(column(select, data_table))```
````